# Nor CkRsa__encryptBytesENC, Neither CkRsa__encryptStringENC of chilkat DLL for Delphi don't encrypt

Tags: delphi, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, chilkat

I want to encrypt a text using PublicKey in Chilkat
but it doesn't work and the error message is: "Private Key Required, privatekey not provided"
**As Chilkat document says** encryption should always use publicKey for encryption
https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/dd_CkRsaRef.html

This is my code and i'm really confused about why my code doesn't work.
This function has a input of Tbytes which contains the ASCII code of the text to be encrypted and text is in Hex mode.

and public key is stored in "C:\PK.txt"
KeyLength shows that I have a 1024 Bit key and even CkRsa_ImportPublicKey returns true
This is the PublicKey **"8e9c531e740e72f386c0a9aad397ab7409efb3ec9177bb8ca341e7c104d72ab5a29489e4e4b6eae731eb3cd1c78672626de664491fcf9134454ca5df3d2779a89dc5e87eeb81b69900d2b86723826ce899a5a749d026b8cb37e11846d45e549d15448d546fef54330b8d6f8f02e22cfd8d4ccb97b3baa75eb9a5a56ff4b00d59"**

I'm using Delphi 10.3 so I can declare inline variables

any answer in any language is ok, just tell me why I've got this error
Thank you in advance

```
function EncryptText(PlainTextByte: TBytes): Boolean;
var InputByteArr: TBytes;
begin
     var RSA3: HCkRsa:= CkRsa_Create();
     Result:= False;
     
     if Not CkRsa_UnlockComponent(RSA3, 's8xxx.xxxxxxxx') then
       begin
            CkRsa_Dispose(RSA3);
            Exit(False);
       end;
     
     var tmp_Enc: PWideChar;
     var  RSA_PublicKey: PWideChar;
     var tmp_File: TStringList:= TStringList.Create;
     tmp_File.LoadFromFile('c:\pk.txt', TEncoding.ANSI);
     var PubKey: String:= StringReplace(tmp_File.Text, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
     var PubKeyStr: String:='<RSAPublicKey><Modulus>' + PubKey + '</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAPublicKey>';
     RSA_PublicKey:= PWideChar(PubKeyStr);
     var PlainText: String:= '';
     bUsePrivateKey := False;
     var EncStr: String:= '';
     var tmp_PlainText: PWideChar;
     SetLength(InputByteArr, Length(PlainTextByte) Div 2);

     for var i := 0 to Length(PlainTextByte) - 1 do // input is Hex
        if i Mod 2 = 0 then
          InputByteArr[i div 2]:= (PlainTextByte[i] * 16) + PlainTextByte[i + 1];

     var InputByteArrPointer: PByte:= Addr(InputByteArr);
     var ckBytes: HCkByteData:= CkByteData_Create();
     CkByteData_borrowData(ckBytes, InputByteArrPointer, Length(InputByteArr));

     if CkRsa_ImportPublicKey(RSA3, RSA_PublicKey) then
       begin
            CkRsa_putOaepPadding(RSA3, False);
            CkRsa_putEncodingMode(RSA3, 'base64');
            var bUsePrivateKey: Boolean:= False; // This tells Chilkat not to use privatekey
            var KeyLength:Integer:= CkRsa_getNumBits(RSA3);  // This shows bit length
            tmp_Enc:= CkRsa__encryptBytesENC(RSA3, ckBytes, bUsePrivateKey); // This doesn't work neither => CkRsa__encryptStringENC()
            tmp_Enc:= CkRsa__lastErrorText(RSA3); // this tells that i need to provide private key to encrypt
            EncStr:= WideCharToString(tmp_Enc);
            tmp_File.Text:= EncStr;
            tmp_File.SaveToFile('c:\output.txt', TEncoding.ANSI);            
            CkByteData_Dispose(ckBytes);            
            InputByteArr:= nil;
            Result:= True;
       end;

     tmp_File.Free;
     tmp_File:= nil;
     CkRsa_Dispose(RSA3);
end;
```

Comment: Why not send a tweet to the author? He gives his twitter account in his website title bar.

Comment: @fpiette I don't have any account in common social medias

Comment: Easy to create one now. You can delete it when you've got your answer.

Comment: The documentation that you linked above states that function `CkRsa__encryptBytesENC` uses [WordBool](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.WordBool) whichs is a 16 bit (two bytes) boolean as third parameter but you use Standard Delphi [Boolean](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Boolean) which is 8 bit (1 byte) in size. I recommend changing your `bUsePrivateKey` variable into `WordBool` type.

Comment: @silverwarior I tried it either, but nothing happened

Comment: @fpiette *"Why not send a tweet to the author?"* Because you're supposed to visit the [support page](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/support.asp) instead.

Comment: @Olivier I missed that. Thanks.